# how to replace a comma with single quote comma in SQLIN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, in-clause

Hi all I have a an where clause like below

```
select * from table1 
where colum1 IN (?parameter)
```

when I pass the values to the parameter they show up like below
`('1,2,3')` but to execute the query I need to change the values as `('1','2','3')`
is there a way to replace the commas with single quotes comma in IN clause directly?

Comment: There is no simple way to do this; what you are thinking of doing will change the input string to another single string, not a list (collection, array, call it whatever you want) of several individual strings. You need to "split the input string" into individual tokens. Read about "split csv" on this site to see how it can be done, the question has been asked many times before.

Comment: I'm not great with Oracle, but isn't it the same as this? [How to split comma separated string and pass to IN clause of select statement](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement)

Answer (score 1):

There is one hack to do what you want, using `like`:

```
select *
from table1 
where ',' || column1 || ',' like '%,' || (?parameter) || ',%';
```

This functions, but it will not make use of an index on `column1`.  You should think about other solutions, such as:

- Parsing the string into a table variable.
- Using `in` with a fixed number of parameters.
- Storing the values in a table.

There may be other Oracle-specific solutions as well.

Comment: "Hack" is perhaps too strong a word. Sure, the optimizer can't do anything with it, but maybe it doesn't need to or it won't cause any significant performance problem. The good thing about this approach (which I was going to suggest too), is it delivers the functionality *now*, so you can move on to delivering other things.

Answer (score 0):

Use MS SQL, you can convert it into table value and using join for your condition, I am not familiar oracle but you can find same way to do it.

```
DECLARE @IDs varchar(max) ='1,2,3';
;WITH Cte AS 
( 
    SELECT
        CAST('<ID>' + REPLACE( @IDs,  ',' , '</ID><ID>') + '</ID>' AS XML) AS IDs 
)

SELECT '''' + Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') +'''' AS ID FROM Cte
    CROSS APPLY Cte.IDs.nodes('/ID') Split(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using with clause. Logic here is to convert each comma separated value into different row.

```
with temp_tab as ( 
  select replace(regexp_substr(parameter, '[^,]+',1, level),'''','') as str
  from dual
  connect by level<= length(regexp_replace(parameter, '[^,]+'))+1 )

select * from table1 where column1 in (select str from temp_tab);
```